# Centering tabs in tablayout

Tags: android, android-tablayout

[image]

How would I place center my tabs in tablayout?

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
     android:id="@+id/fraghome_tab_layout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/standardBlue"/>
```

I've tried `app:tabGravity="center"` but it doesn't make it completely centered, it fills out the entire layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/fraghome_tab_layout"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/standardBlue"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
    app:tabGravity="center"
    app:tabMode="fixed"/>
```

I have got the output by `app:tabGravity="center"`

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: @davids. i have got the output by making it center by tabgravity

Comment: I figured out the reason why. The length of the tab indicator is based on the length of the longest word. 1/2 of my tab names was too long thats why it wasn't centered.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following line to the Tab layout to align the text to the center.

> app:tabGravity="fill"

**Screenshot** :

[image]